# twitter app shows old pic of followers

Tags: twitter

I have observed that, twitter app doesn't show your's follower updated pic/profile; rather it continue to show old. Is it same with others? Is this twitter app or window issue? Even I updated my profile & header image, it still shows old header pic however it shows updated profile pic.

if you reinstall app, it shows new pic/header pic.

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously an app issue.

I don't know which Twitter app you're using, but I'm guessing it's the official one. The app actually refreshes the profile pics after a while but indeed it takes long for it to do so.

There no workaround that I know of. This is one of the reasons I use a third party Twitter app. If the delaying of the pics is a major issue for you, you can try your luck elsewhere.

And don't forget to leave a comment in the app review section to let the developers know.

Comment: Thanks. Am using official twitter app however if it displays updated one with delay it is not major issue for me.

Comment: i will check it app really reflects delaying in profile update.